# PHP file neither moved nor unmoved

Tags: php, file, upload, move

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. When I run the following code:

```
$uref = APACHE_ROOT .  UPLOAD_PATH . $applicant . "_ref_{$email}_{$year}"; 

if ( !move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uref ) ) {
   echo "Move failed";
} elseif ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['ref']['tmp_name'], $uref) )     {
    echo "Move succeeded";
}
```

Neither statement gets returned. Both paths exist; one file was successfully uploaded and this started happening after only the second upload attempt.

Any ideas why? 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ( !move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uref ) ) {
   echo "Move failed";
} elseif ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['ref']['tmp_name'], $uref) )     {
    echo "Move succeeded";
}
```

If your first call returns true, because the file is moved, then the second will return false, because the file is no longer there.

You're much better off just having a simple `if / else` - the first call can be either true or false, so you don't need to re-check.

Answer (score 1):

First, is `$uref = APACHE_ROOT .  UPLOAD_PATH . $applicant . "_ref_{$email}_{$year}";` a directory?

If it is, then you are trying to write to a directory, which is probably going to fail if the directory already exists.

Also, only check the running once.

The first time, `move_file_uploaded` will be executed to check if it is negative. It's obviously true, so it goes to the second to check if it's true, and it's returning false.

Do this instead:

```
$uref = APACHE_ROOT .  UPLOAD_PATH . $applicant . "_ref_{$email}_{$year}"; 

if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uref )){
   echo "Move succeeded";
} else {
   echo "Move failed";
}
```